# How to update constraints based on user input

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

I have a view controller view with 3 column sections (called legs, `aView`, `bView`, and `cView`) by default. The user can switch it between 2 and 3 in a settings menu that gets presented modally over the same screen.

I'm trying to get the columns to take up space equally on the screen, so when there are 3 columns, they each take up roughly 1/3 of the width (ignoring padding), and when there are 2, they each take up roughly 1/2.

My current method is setting some constraints that are always active, and then for the ones that change depending on the number of columns, using an `if` statement. I tried some variations of `layoutIfNeeded()`, `removeConstraints`, and others but not entirely sure how to implement them.

For some clarification on the code, `xView` is the column view, which contains `xTitle` and `xTextView`. There is also a `mainButton` above the text views, and `button1` below the text views. This all exists inside a `contentView` and `scrollView` setup.

```
let sidePadding: CGFloat = 15


func placeViews() { // run in viewWillAppear

        let alwaysConstraints = [
            aView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 25),
            aView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: sidePadding),
            aView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bView.leftAnchor),
            bView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aView.topAnchor),
            bView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aView.bottomAnchor),
            aTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aView.topAnchor),
            bTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aTitle.topAnchor),
            aTitle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aView.centerXAnchor),
            bTitle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bView.centerXAnchor),
            aTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 25),
            bTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aTextView.topAnchor),
            aTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aView.bottomAnchor),
            bTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aTextView.bottomAnchor),
            aTextView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aView.centerXAnchor),
            bTextView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bView.centerXAnchor),
            aTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aView.widthAnchor),
            bTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bView.widthAnchor),
            bView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aView.widthAnchor),

            // Restrict buttons to leg views
            button1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonHeight),
            button1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
            button1.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -20),
            button1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aView.bottomAnchor, constant: 40),

            // Restrict button to bottom
            button1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
        ]




        let twoLegConstraints = [
            aView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (view.frame.width - (sidePadding * 2) / 2)),
            bView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -sidePadding),
        ]

        let threeLegConstraints = [
            aView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (view.frame.width - (sidePadding * 2)) / 3),
            bView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.leftAnchor),
            cView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -sidePadding),
            cView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aView.topAnchor),
            cView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aView.bottomAnchor),
            cTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aTitle.topAnchor),
            cTitle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.centerXAnchor),
            cTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aTextView.topAnchor),
            cTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aTextView.bottomAnchor),
            cTextView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.centerXAnchor),
            cTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.widthAnchor),
            cView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aView.widthAnchor),
        ]





        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(alwaysConstraints)

        if legs == 2 {
            cView.isHidden = true
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(twoLegConstraints)
        } else if legs == 3 {
            cView.isHidden = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(threeLegConstraints)
        }
    }
```

At the moment, the screen starts with 3 by default, and it works perfectly (each ~1/3 screen width). Then the user can switch it to 2, and it works perfectly again (each ~1/2 screen width). Then switching back to 3, the first two don't change at all, and the third column appears on the right edge of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stack view with `distribution = .fillEqually`. It will take care of the layout and constraints automatically when you set the `isHidden` property of any of your views.

Comment: Ugh thank you!! This is my first app made fully programmatically, so that solution didn't jump out at me. I also learned about needing to use `addArrangedSubview` instead of `addSubview`, for any future readers. Gah so much time wasted. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help!